# How to correctly add dollar sign to a string?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, format, currency

I have this SQL code:

```
LPAD(to_char(amount_sold, 'FM999,999,999,990D'),35, ' ') AS amount_sold
```

It outputs format like `6,664,444`. But I want `6,664,444 $`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'L'`:

```
lpad(to_char(amount_sold, 'FM999,999,999,990 LD'),35, ' ') AS amount_sold
```

This relies on locale setting [`lc_monetary`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-MONETARY) to choose the relevant symbol. If it is not properly set, you can always concatenate an explicit `'$'` in the format specifier:

```
lpad(to_char(amount_sold, 'FM999,999,999,990 "$"D'),35, ' ') AS amount_sold
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LPAD(to_char(amount_sold, 'FM999,999,999,990 $'),20, ' ') AS amount_sold,
```